# Rotate positions of three game object when clicking a UI button

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

As the title says, I have a scene with three objects, a cube, a sphere, and a cylinder-like you can see in the image below.

[image: starting scene]

What I'm trying to achieve is that when I press the "Rotate" button, the three objects rotate in an anti-clockwise direction, so the cylinder goes where the cube was, the cube goes where the sphere was, and the sphere goes where the cylinder was. If I click the button again, they rotate once again and so on. So far, I managed to make them rotate around an empty object at the center of the "triangle" they form with their initial position.

This is what happens when I first click the "Rotate" button:

[image]

As you can see, the object rotates, but they don't keep the same coordinate of the object that was previously in that position, so I was thinking of having them exchange coordinates. How can I achieve that or making them rotate how I want to?

Here is the code I wrote so far:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class RotateObject : MonoBehaviour {

    //rotating objects
    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject cube;

    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject sphere;

    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject cylinder;

    private Renderer cubeRenderer;
    private Renderer sphereRenderer;
    private Renderer cylinderRenderer;

    //rotation target
    public GameObject target;

    private void Start() {

        cubeRenderer = cube.GetComponent<Renderer>();
        sphereRenderer = sphere.GetComponent<Renderer>();
        cylinderRenderer = cylinder.GetComponent<Renderer>();
        gameObject.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(Rotate);
    }

    void Rotate() {

        //rotate objects by 120 degrees
        cube.transform.RotateAround(target.transform.position, Vector3.up, -120);
        sphere.transform.RotateAround(target.transform.position, Vector3.up, -120);
        cylinder.transform.RotateAround(target.transform.position, Vector3.up, -120);
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance for helping me!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to make an object(s) rotate around a point is to have it/them as a child of the point then rotate the point itself.

[Object Hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFqKD.png)

Rotator Script to be put on the parent object:

```
public class RotateObjects : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] Button rotateButton;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rotateButton.onClick.RemoveAllListeners();
        rotateButton.onClick.AddListener(RotateClockwise);
    }

    void RotateClockwise()
    {
        float newRotation = (360 / transform.childCount);
        transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0, newRotation, 0));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried this but it does exaclty the same as my script, except that it moves in a clockwise direction, what I'm trying to achieve is that the three object have to "swap coordinates" basically with the object next to them in a counter clockwise direction. By rotating them I don't achieve this because they are slightly misplaced: I think the problem might need a "geometrical" solution since the three objects don't make a perfect triangle.

Comment: Yes sorry it does do clockwise, to do counter-clockwise set the newRotation to be negative when you do the transform.Rotate. I should have also noted that the parent's initial rotation needs to be set so that one of your objects is in the position you want it to be in. This does require you to manually place your child objects in the correct spacing around the parent but because it calculates the newRotation based on the number of children you can increase or decrease the number of objects without having to change the script.

Comment: Don't worry, I actually managed to make it work, the problem was that the empty they rotate around wasn't at the center of the triangle they form, thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You are rotating around an object. Like the earth rotates around the sun; that means it will change its position. Use

```
transform.rotation = new Quaternion(rotx, roty, rotz, rotw);
```

or

```
transform.Rotate(rotx, roty, rotz);
```

Instead of rotating about a point rotate the shape, it's self.